# Calculating the length of a cord and a bizarre result

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to calculate the length of a cord within the confines of a circle/ellipse in p5.js.
The parameters given are `values` and `size`. `values` is a simple array of 3 values: Hue, Saturation, and Brightness. The more important parameter is `size` which is the width and height of the shape (circle).
As the `for` loop iterates through the length of `size` the math is performed to derive half the cord length via Pythagorean theorem. `r` is half the size of `size`, or the radius. `y` is the current value of the `for` loop. `r^2 - |y-r|^2 = x^2` where `x` is half the cord length (the absolute value is not required but it's more or less just for ensuring and debugging).
However, whenever I square `r` in the equation I receive the odd shape below. When I don't square `r` within the equation, I get the rotated square. The circle in the background is meant to represent the current HSL I am trying to display.

This happens when I don't square `r`
[image: A rotated square in offset with the circle]

This happens when I square `r`
[image: Wird pattern]

This is my current code:

```
this.draw = function(values, size) {
  //angleMode(DEGREES);
  this.gap = values[2];
  this.r = size / 2;
  this.lCol = map(values[1], 0, 100, 10, 70)

  strokeUniform(this.lCol);
  fillUniform(map(values[2], 0, 100, this.lCol + 20, 240));
  strokeWeight(map(values[0], 0, 360, 0, 10));
  translate(this.r, this.r, 0);

  for (y = 0; y < size; y++) {
    if (y % Math.floor(this.gap / 2) == 0) {
      if (this.r > y) {
        this.len = ((this.r ^ 2 - (Math.abs(this.r - y) ^ 2))) ^ 0.5;
        line(0 - this.len, 0 - (this.r - y), 0 + this.len, 0 - (this.r - y));
      } else {
        this.len = ((this.r ^ 2 - ((y - this.r) ^ 2))) ^ 0.5;
        line(0 - this.len, y - this.r, 0 + this.len, y - this.r);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read up on what the `^` operator in Java does and why it's not the same as `Math.sqrt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't doing what you expected it to:

```
r^2
```

The `^` symbol is the [bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR) and it works on binary numbers. For example:

```
var x = 5; // 0101
var y = 1; // 0001
var z = x ^ y; // 0100
console.log(z); // 4
```

In other words, the XOR operator looks at each digit in the binary representation of your number and the resulting digit is a 1 if only one of the arguments is a 1.

More info here:

- [JavaScript operators](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp)
- [Bitwise XOR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_XOR)

You probably want the `Math.pow()` function. More info can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp).

Better yet, P5.js provides a `sq()` function. More info can be found in [the P5.js reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/sq).

Similarly, look for a `Math.sqrt()` or the P5.js `sqrt()` function instead of using `^ 0.5`.